# Select all elements of a ID with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is the code:

```
<div id="divFrame"> <div> <img /> </div> <div> </div> <p> </p> </div>
```

I want to select all these elements.
I have tried the following with no luck

```css
#divFrame *
#divFrame > *
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `#divFrame *` works for me in Google Chrome (didnt check in FF) http://jsfiddle.net/3bEav/ , check you CSS code before that particular selector, there might be some syntax error.

Comment: Where is the last closing `</div>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither will select all elements. The first will select all descendants (children and grandchildren), while the second only selects the children of the div, namely the two divs and the p, but not the img. Neither will select #divFrame itself.

To select them all, you will need

```
#divFrame, #divFrame *
```

This is actionally a combination of two selectors. The first selects #divFrame while the second selects all its descendants.

Comment: Your terminology is way off - the *second* one will only select all children, namely the two divs and the p, while the first will select all descendants including the img. The child selector is `>`, not the space; the space is called the descendant selector.

Comment: OP:`I want to select all these elements`

Comment: @Musa: Yeah it seems to be missing one last closing tag.

Comment: Please/Kindly eloborate as I read that the universal selector is implied and not explicited when it is not the only selector - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/universalselector

Comment: @Jawad: "It can be implied (and therefore omitted) if it isn’t the only component of the simple selector." This means if it's separated by combinators like space or `>` then it's not implied.

Comment: @BoltClock: Great Catch. Thanks. Little think and slow up there I am.

Comment: @BoltClock. Yes the terminology could have been better. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all these elements

```
#divFrame, #divFrame div, #divFrame img, #divFrame p
{
property: value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close one of your `div` so your code is not working.

> I want to select all these elements.

Use `div, img, p`